# JavaScript problem in a WordPress PAGE

Tags: javascript

I did a simple HTML page which has JavaScript as following:

```
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var y = document.querySelector('input[name="mum1"]:checked').value;  
    var z = document.querySelector('input[name="num2"]:checked').value;
    var x = +y + +z;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

It works fine by itself. When I add it to a WordPress website(add HTML in a page). 
The error message comes like this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
```

I guess this cause by JavaScript conflict, my WordPress website use jquery.

How to solve the problem.

Comment: You've added it how exactly? In a page template?

Comment: yeah, I mean in a page template.

Comment: Where in the page template did you add this?

Comment: Create a new empty template which get content from THE PAGE. Then paste the code to Page in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var x = +y + +z;
```

to

```
var x = Number(y) + Number(z);
```

Done~